# Got Questionmarks during updating into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encoding

When am going to make an update into my data base from hosted application online .. i got into whole cells of updated Row .. Question marks  '???' .. is that conflict with language .. cauz i write into Arabic and update also into Arabic . but if i Wrote into English Update Success .. and for notice . inserting by Arabic or English is Successful .. but only into  Updating English Success and Arabic Alphabetic converts to  '?????' questionmarks and iam using .. SQL Server 2008 of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Could be an issue with your character encoding - it would be helpful to know your actual RDBMS.  Although that would often end in error...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To preserve caracter encoding in your oracle  or MSSQL database, use a 'N' in front of your text values:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourcolumn = N'newtext';
```

:-)

Comment: So what can i do if my database is SQL . ?

Comment: You can do the same thing in Microsoft SQL, but you didn't specify what DB you were using in your question.

Comment: sry i forgot but modified it to >> am using SQL Server 2008 of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: yeah u are Right .. cauz the Server is not supporting Arabic Language .. just only English and Latin .. so 2 answers 1-to change unicode of the DB by using that command .. 

or by using like "Francis " N before insert or update 

ALTER DATABASE DatabseName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS

Answer (score 3):

I think you may use `char` or `varchar` data type for your field in the table.

In MSSQL there are two different types for character data type
`char` and `nchar`. (Also there is  two different type: `varchar` and `nvarchar`)

If you have sites that support multiple languages, consider using the Unicode 'nchar' or 'nvarchar' data types to minimize character conversion issues.

Comment: i changed the datatype of columns .. like u advised me .. but also no things affected .. still Arabic Language Converts to ???? Question marks .